# Problems Injecting Custom Authentication Manager

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm attempting to use a custom authentication manager but the standard Provider manager is being called to .authenticate. I suspect it has something to do with either the AuthSever or Web Config. Any help is greatly appreciated.

AuthServer configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private final DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public AuthServerConfig(DataSource dataSource){
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Autowired
MicrosJwtConfig microsJwtConfig;


@Autowired
@Qualifier("microsProviderManager")
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource);
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
            .tokenServices(microsJwtConfig.microsTokenServices())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
    security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    security.passwordEncoder(encoder());
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
}
}
```

WebSecurity config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
@Autowired
private MECAuthenticationProvider mecAuthenticationProvider;

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return new MicrosProviderManager(clientDetailsService, mecAuthenticationProvider );
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("actuator/health").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("oauth/token").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("actuator/info").permitAll();
}
}
```

Comment: By changing the grant type in the DB and request to username and password I've been able to successfully hit the custom AuthenticationManager. However I have not been able to diagnose why it won't work with client credentials.